# Will I get read_stream, publish_actions and user_photos permissions for my TV app

Tags: facebook, permissions

Can i get read_stream, publish_actions and user_photos permissions for my TV app? There is no other official Facebook client present in my TV.

I already have my Facebook app running with all these permissions. I need to upgrade my app with graph API 2.2. But due to version and changes in permissions, I am not clear whether I will get approval for these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

About `read_stream`:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and **TV apps will not be granted this permission**.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

If you get the other permissions approved only depends on your implementation. For example, you are not allowed to prefill the message (or the photo caption) if you want to post something with `publish_actions`.